# JavaFX Symbol not found, referring from class

Tags: java, class, javafx, symbols

this might be a stupid question but I'm trying to access a text area from my new Gui through the controller which uses its own class (as simple as they are) when i run the program it comes up with the symbol not defined. I'm not sure where im going wrong.

Here is the Code:

External Class

```
package dataget;

import java.io.*;

public class ReadWrite {

    public void ReadFileContents(String fileName) {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            int lineNumber = 0;
            int currentLine;
            String lines[];

            while (in.readLine() != null) {
                lineNumber++;
            }
            in.close();

            lines = new String[lineNumber];
            BufferedReader inLines = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

            for (currentLine = 0; currentLine < lineNumber;) {
                lines[currentLine] = inLines.readLine();
                txtareaOutput.appendText(lines[currentLine]);
                currentLine++;
            }

            inLines.close();

            txtareaStatus.appendText("Lines in File: " + lineNumber);



        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
        }
    }
```

And now the Controller Class:

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TextField txtName;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtAge;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox comboGender;
    @FXML
    private Button btnRead;
    @FXML
    private Button btnWrite;
    @FXML
    private TextArea txtareaStatus;
    @FXML
    private TextArea txtareaOutput;

    @FXML
    public void clickRead(){
        ReadWrite read = new ReadWrite();
        read.ReadFileContents("data/dylans/data.txt");
    }
}
```

I omitted a few lines since they are irrelevant (they are all in the same DataGet Package)

And i keep getting "error: cannot find symbol":

```
Compiling 2 source files to C:\Apps\NetBeans 7.3.1\Dylans Projects\DataGet\build\classes
C:\Apps\NetBeans 7.3.1\Dylans Projects\DataGet\src\dataget\ReadWrite.java:28:
error: cannot find symbol txtareaOutput.appendText(lines[currentLine]);
symbol: variable txtareaOutput
location: class ReadWrite
C:\Apps\NetBeans 7.3.1\Dylans Projects\DataGet\src\dataget\ReadWrite.java:34:
error: cannot find symbol txtareaStatus.appendText("Lines in File: " + lineNumber);
symbol: variable txtareaStatus
location: class ReadWrite 2 errors
```

Do i have to declare the textarea within the original class file where the object is created from?

thanks.

Comment: *"i keep getting "error: cannot find symbol"."* => when, how, where? When compiling? On what line? etc.

Comment: This is the Exact Error output:-

Compiling 2 source files to C:\Apps\NetBeans 7.3.1\Dylans Projects\DataGet\build\classes
C:\Apps\NetBeans 7.3.1\Dylans Projects\DataGet\src\dataget\ReadWrite.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
                txtareaOutput.appendText(lines[currentLine]);
  symbol:   variable txtareaOutput
  location: class ReadWrite
C:\Apps\NetBeans 7.3.1\Dylans Projects\DataGet\src\dataget\ReadWrite.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
            txtareaStatus.appendText("Lines in File: " + lineNumber);
  symbol:   variable txtareaStatus
  location: class ReadWrite
2 errors

Comment: Please try to include all relevant information directly in your question. I have added the details.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply access to a `MainController` field `txtareaStatus` in `ReadWrite`.
If you want really do that (which is a bad idea) you have to :

- make `txtareaStatus` public, or provide a public getter.
- instantiate `MainController` and get your `txtareaStatus`.

---

As a suggestion, you have to separate the process of fetching the text from the process of updating the `UI` (`TextArea`), notice that I'm reading the file in another thread than the `JavaFX Thread` to avoid liveness problems in the case of big text file.

First, you have to design a **File Reader** class that will return a list of lines (`String`)

```
public class TextFileReader {

        @SuppressWarnings("NestedAssignment")
        public List<String> read(File file) {
            List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            String line;
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    lines.add(line);
                }
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TextFileReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            return lines;
        }
```

In the `FXML` controller that reference the `TextArea` and a `Button` to update it :

```
public class ViewController implements Initializable {

        @FXML
        private TextField urlTextField;
        @FXML 

        private TextArea linesTextArea;
        private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(ViewController.class.getName());
        private Future<List<String>> future;
        private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        private TextFileReader reader = new TextFileReader();

        public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        }

        @FXML
        @SuppressWarnings("NestedAssignment")
        public void showFileLines() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

            future = executorService.submit(new Callable<List<String>>() {
                public List<String> call() throws Exception {
                    return reader.read(new File(ViewController.this.urlTextField.getText()));
                }
            });

            List<String> lines = future.get();
                executorService.shutdownNow();
            linesTextArea.clear();
            for (String line : lines ) {
                linesTextArea.appendText(line + "\n");
            }  

        }
    }
```

You can access to the complete source code in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/tarrsalah/6340796).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've only been looking at JAVAFX for a few days so forgive my ignorance.

How am i able to output the returned strings from the object to UI components such as the TextArea?

Comment: Encapsulation @DylanBenton 

It's bad practice to update UI components in a file other than the Controller as it can cause some massive issues with lag (I've learned this from experience).  That's why tarrsalah here shows you to set the information in the TextArea from the Controller and not your reader class.